# turn list into string for tokenization

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, nlp, spacy

I am trying to loc a sentence from a dataframe based on it's report_id. But when I try to tokenize the sentence I get an error. I want to check for each word from the sentence if it exists in a list stored in row.keywords.

Here is my code:

```
def sentence_color(start = 50, end = 51):
    for index, row in df_lda_result[start:end].iterrows():
        report = [rep.REPORTS for index, rep in data.iterrows() if rep.REPORT_ID == row.report_id]
        print(report)
        doc = nlp(report)
        tokens = [token.text for token in doc]
        
        for word in tokens:
            if not word in row.keywords:
                print('False:', word)
            else:
                print('True:', word)

sentence_color()
```

And this is the error: *TypeError: Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got list)*

Comment: It would help immensely if you could share some [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you provide some sample data and expected output, you can probably get an answer much sooner.